# WCF service gets slow when parallel

Tags: .net, performance, wcf, jmeter, server

In our production environment we have started to experience slow WCF calls (inbound). We used to be able to send a response in 60-80ms but now it sometimes takes 500-800ms or even more.

I started doing tests in a non production environment by simulating live traffic with JMeter and measuring response times. The JMeter testplan is created so it hits our different endpoints with approximately same weight as in our live environment.

For now im hitting 9 different methods on 4 different endpoints, some are RESTful and some are SOAP.

When I set each threadgroup to one thread (9 threads/users in total) and start a test with a fixed duration of 30 seconds, I get response times in avg. of 45ms. During the 30 secounds I hit the endpoints 500 times.

The test is setup with constant throughput timers, so increasing the number of threads will keep the same throughput.

When I increase the threads to 10 for each thread group (now a total of 90 threads) the response times increase drastically to an avg. of around 140ms
Still hitting the endpoints around 500 times on a 30 seconds period tells me that the issue/bottleneck has to do with parallelism on our servers. But I can't seem to figure out where to look.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone has some input on this issue, is there a explanation for this behaviour or do I have to look into configuration of our WCF endpoints, could the IIS have some relevant settings or anything else?

Our applications are running under IIS 8.5 on windows 2012 R2 servers and uses .NET 4.5

Thanks in advance

Comment: what are the methods doing? SQL-queries? - do they meet in a SQL or IO bottleneck maybe?

Comment: Yes, they fetch user information from a seperate sql server (or from cache), could it be the sql server that slows down the calls? How can I detect this bottleneck if that is the case?

Comment: of course it could be the SQL-Server - take a look at the SQL-Server-Activity monitor : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377023%28v=bts.70%29.aspx to get further information of the SQL-Servers-load (btw: Is the SQL-Server an Express edition?)

Comment: It's not express. It's a MS sql 2012 standard edition.

Comment: I just did a load test against a method on a wcf endpoint that does not connect to the db (actually it do not do anything maybe i shuld make it sleep or something) The result is as follows (all durations 30sec and 450 calls) 1 thread: Avg response: 8ms, 5: 11ms, 10: 14ms, 20:28ms, 50: 32ms

Comment: ok - so the empty method runs fast.. i belive the much parallel amount of calls against the WCF-Method & the work to do behind is the problem. maybe you can optimize your method or sql query. I would check the InstanceContextMode too - do you need an instance per session/call? - take a look at this codeprtoject article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of reasons for your issue :

- slow database with concurrent sql queries
- misconfigured sql server
- network contention due to bandwidth
- misconfigured IIS
- issue in code affecting concurrency (locking)
- ...

It is impossible to guess without more elements